# Pc Black screen then shuts down while logging in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, shutdown, black-screen-of-death

I was working on my papers recently, but then I took a 30 min break. So I shutdown my pc and went for a break. When I came back, powered up my pc, and entered my password, the screen  immediately blacked out and the pc shut down. I kept o trying but it keeps doing the same thing.

Please I need my papers done ASAP! No one would believe that this is happening to my pc.

Comment: Can you describe anything that you were doing, any special application you were using, etcetera. If nothing else works, try to access the hard drive from another computer.

Comment: I would boot into safe mode to access your paper for the time being.  Two failed attempts of loading Windows should enable the recovery option to boot to safe mode.  Just reset your computer while Windows is loading.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your battery. I'm not sure why but sometimes I have weird issues with my computer where once in a while I turn on my computer and the screen will not turn on. The computer is still running, but the screen doesn't work even if I restart it. Pull your battery out and put it back in after 3 seconds. It might not work, but that might be a hardware issue.